# How to solve $\mathop{max}_\limits{F} \ Tr(F^TAF)$, where $A=A^T$, $F \in \Bbb \{1, 0\}^{n \times c}$ is an indicator matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, discrete-optimization

For indicator matrix $F$, each row of $F$ has only one 1 and each column of $F$ has at least one 1.

An example in python is as follow

```
import numpy as np
n = 5
c = 3
F = np.zeros((n, c))
rand_num = np.zeros((n, 1))
while len(np.unique(rand_num)) != c:
    rand_num = np.random.randint(0, c, (n, 1))
F[np.arange(n).reshape(n,1), rand_num] = 1
print(F)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "each array of F has a least one 1"  Do you mean that each column of $F$ has at least one 1?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Sorry, I use the wrong word. I mean "each column".

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry, I made mistake, it should be "each column of F has at least one 1"

Comment: A hint is $\text{Tr}(F^T A F) = \text{Tr}(A F F^T ) $, you know just have to determine what kind of matrix $F^TF$ is.